# Write R pin to Google Drive without authentication

Tags: r, google-drive-api, pins

I am using the `pins` R package and the `board_gdrive()` function to create a hosted board on my Google Drive. My goal is to have a hosted shiny app that pulls pin data from the Google Drive board. However, it appears that Google Drive requires authentication verification each time. Is there a way to not require, or have the authentication stored with the board so that manual interaction is not required? Here is the code I have been using

```
# Google Drive board
board <- pins::board_gdrive(googledrive::as_id("https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/my-folder-abc123"))
```

Comment: I think what you may need to do is set up an API key. I don't use google drive, but perhaps this is useful: https://support.google.com/googleapi/answer/6158862?hl=en

Comment: @r2evans api key will only give you access to public data. Not private user data that will require authorization.

Comment: You need to store the response from the authorization it should contain a refresh token that you can use to request a new access token when you need one rather than requesting authorization again.